# Debugging PHP error that happens after AJAX call by generic JS function

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, debugging

I have a little bit of a confusing situation :)

I have a JavaScript function which is called by a few different pages.  This JavaScript page then calls some server-side PHP code.  About 98% of the time, there is no problem.

But sometimes the JavaScript does not pass an id parameter that it is supposed to, and that generates errors.

My problem is that I can not track down the page which makes the call to the JS function which then generates the PHP call with the error.

Any idea how I could track this down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your PHP script does its work, send the `HTTP_REFERRER` to the error log.  Add the date & time, and `$_GET` vars for more info. This info should already be in your web server access log, but if you need the `$_POST` vars too you'll want to create a custom message into the error log.

```
// Simple:
error_log("AJAX call from {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']}", 0);

// Fancy:
error_log(strftime("Y-m-d H:M:S") . " AJAX call from {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']}; POST: var1={$_POST['var1']} var2={$_POST['var2']}", 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` on the PHP side to try and determine where the request came from.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the Net tab in Firebug.  This traces all HTTP requests, including the AJAX call.  If you are passing parameters, you can see that too.  Click the tiny + button next to the request in Firebug to see details in a tabbed pane including passed parameters, even JSON objects if they are passed.